# Load data to Parse.com daily through API

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to load/import data through third party API to Parse.com daily?

To be more specific, I want to load data from https://api.sample.com/event.json?key=1234 to Parse.com daily. And then sort those data on Parse. And then iOS users pull data from Parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Parse provide a REST API for all collections (db tables) or you could write your own custom code to load the data if you want to add a business rules layer.

You just need to watch your volume of JSON data that you are posting.

I should also add that since you want to do this daily you will need run a daily batch job to do this. Parse has this ability or you can initiative this process manually yourself. It depends how automated this needs to be.